# Angular 2 strange behaiviour: Root element style properties are empty strings

Tags: typescript, angular

im currently experimenting with Angular2 and got to the point, where i want to have dynamic style extension im Angular2 components. To get things more clear, here is some code.

**main.ts**

```
import {bootstrap}    from 'angular2/platform/browser';
import {App} from './app'

bootstrap(App).then(error => console.log(error));
```

**app.ts**

```
import { Component } from 'angular2/core';
import { Button } from './button';

@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    template: `<button [style.background]="'green'">Hallo Welt</button>`,
    directives: [Button]
})
export class App { }
```

**button.ts**

```
import {Component, Input, ElementRef, Renderer} from "angular2/core";
import {BrowserDomAdapter} from "angular2/src/platform/browser/browser_adapter";

@Component({
    selector: 'button',
    templateUrl: '<span [style.color]="test"><ng-content></ng-content></span>',
    providers: [BrowserDomAdapter]
})
export class Button {
    test: string;

    constructor(private renderer:Renderer, private elementRef:ElementRef, dom: BrowserDomAdapter) {
        let styles = elementRef.nativeElement.style;
        console.log(styles);

        this.test = styles['background'] || 'red';
        console.log(this.test);
    }
}
```

Now to something what i would call a strange behaviour. Just in case: Im am not very familiar with DOM manipulations, but i spent hours now in this problem without getting an answer.

When you run this app, you get the following output in the console:

- CSSStyleDeclaration {...}
- red*

*styles['background'] is just an empty string

But in the CSSStyleDeclaration 'background' is set as "green", just as expected, because it is inline style.

To test it i also tried it with different browsers (just Chrome and Firefox here) and tested the 'style'-Property on this website(It works fine here):

> http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_style_get_elmnt

After all this testing i did not came to an adequate solution. Even the BrowserDomAdapter does not work, because it uses the exact same code, to get to the style properties.

Is this a bug of the Angular2 Framework. If yes, it is reported and are there any workarounds. If not, are there any workarounds, or will it be changed in the future.

The feature is not extremely neccesary, but will help me with my work. The reason i need this, is because i am using dynamically generated stylesheets and the user of my components should be able to override them with ngStyle and the '[style.property]' syntax of Angular2. Please note, that i wont use the 'style'-Property of the Component-Decorator and just ovveride them, for some reasons.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I got an answer to my problem while debugging in firefox. It is now clear, why this is happening. In fact what the browser is showing is version of the 'style'-Property that is newer than the version, when my constructor is called.

The style is just not applied yet but i currently do not know, where it is applied.

Update:
I got it now. Okay, almost. I do not exactly know where the style is applied, but this is not really neccesary to do what i want. Just one thing to keep in mind. The constructor is to early to do DOM manipulations in Angular2. It is neccesary to use other lifecycle methods like 'ngOnInit' or use the 'host'-Property of the Component decorator to achieve the exact behaviour.

Here is some code to explain that text above. I just updated the 'button.ts' so use the files in the question as a reference for the other app files.

**button.ts**

```
import {Component, Input, ElementRef, Renderer, Inject, OnInit} from "angular2/core";
import {BrowserDomAdapter} from 'angular2/platform/browser';

@Component({
    selector: 'button',
    templateUrl: 'app/button.html',
    providers: [BrowserDomAdapter]
})
export class Button implements OnInit {
    get test() {
        let dom = this.dom
        let root = this.elementRef.nativeElement;

        return dom.getStyle(root, 'background-color') || 'red';
    }

    constructor(private renderer:Renderer, private elementRef:ElementRef, private dom: BrowserDomAdapter) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        let dom = this.dom
        let renderer = this.renderer;
        let root = this.elementRef.nativeElement;

        if(dom.hasStyle(root, 'background-color')) {
            let backgroundColor = dom.getStyle(root, 'background-color');

            renderer.setElementStyle(root, 'color', backgroundColor);
        }
    }
}
```

This is a solution to my problem and obviously it is not a bug, but sadly this is not documented. I hope i could help someone.